# adding relationship entiey properties

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

i`m new to programming and neo4j also ,

how i must set properties on relationship entity in spring data ,

i create class for relationship and annotated in way in all document available
but i can`t find any example for adding relationship with properties on sdn

when i create 2 nodes and relate them by setting relation property in the node , it works but without info on it ,
how or when i must populate a relationship properties between 2 nodes ? 
please give me sample .
tanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your are looking for are so called rich relationships or relationship entities. Instead of linking two types directly you will link them via sth. like

```
@RelationshipEntity("Relationship_Type")
public class MyRelationship {

  @StartNode
  private A startNode;

  @EndNOde
  private B endNode;
}
```

and use this in `A` for example like this

```
@NodeEntity
public class A {

// id, etc.

@Relationship("Relationship_Type")
private MyRelationship myRelationship;

}
```

This is more comprehensive covered [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:annotating-entities:relationship-entity).